# C - same data in dynamic struct

Tags: c, list, dynamic, struct

Here's my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define STR_LEN 255
    #define TRUE 1

    typedef struct
    {
        int id;
        char text[STR_LEN];
        char answer[4][STR_LEN];
        int correct_answer;
        char date[STR_LEN];
        char author[STR_LEN];
        int difficulty;
    } Question;

    typedef struct
    {
        Question* new_question;
        struct List* next;
    } List;

    List* listFromFile(List* root, FILE* file)
    {
        List* current_item;
        Question* q;
        root = (List* ) malloc(sizeof(List));
        q = (Question* ) malloc(sizeof(Question));
        if(!fread(q, sizeof(Question), 1, file))
        {
            printf("No data in the file");
            exit(1);
        }
        root->new_question = q;
        root->next = NULL;

        do
        {

            current_item = (List* ) malloc(sizeof(List));
            current_item->next = NULL;
            if (!fread(q, sizeof(Question), 1 , file))
            {
                free(current_item);
                break;
            }
            current_item->new_question = q;
            current_item->next = root;
            root = current_item;

        }
        while(TRUE);

        free(q);
        return root;
}
int main()
{
    List* root = NULL;
    List* item;
    int count_id = 1;
    int choice;
    system("CLS");
    FILE* file;
    if ((file = fopen ("questions.bin", "rb")) != NULL)
    {
        root = listFromFile(root, file);
        count_id = root->new_question->id;
        printf("Questions loaded!\n\n\n\n");
        if ((fclose(file)) != 0)
            printf("ERROR - cannot close file!\n");
    }
    else printf("No questions found! Please add questions.\n\n\n");
```

The problem is that when i try to print the list there is same information in each list element and im not knowing why. Fortunately the list elements are the same number as in the file, but something is wrong with that how i put the information in them. Has anybody idea why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same allocated memory block pointed by `q` to assign questions to nodes, but you are also overwriting it each time you read a new question. You need to `malloc` each question to allocate unique buffers to them.

```
do {

   current_item = (List* ) malloc(sizeof(List));
   q = (Question* ) malloc(sizeof(Question));
   /* ... */
} while (1);
```

Comment: Would also suggest checking all the malloc outputs to catch NULL returns

Answer (score 0):

Add a point.

```
    do
    {

        current_item = (List* ) malloc(sizeof(List));
        if (!current_item)
        {
            printf("malloc error\n");
            break;
        }
        ...
    }
    while(TRUE);

    //free(q); //you couldn't free the q pointer here or else may cause segfault
    return root;
```

because of your code in main function.

```
    count_id = root->new_question->id;
```